# How can i fire an event in window and handle it in UserControl? C# WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm using my usercontrol in window. I want to do something in usercontrol when window's StateChanged event fires.

I want to send statechanged event to usercontrol.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Declare a property in your UserControl and set it when the window state changes.

Comment: You want to bind StateChanged event to a method. Can you show us what you've tried and also do you use MVVM pattern?

Comment: you can accept an answer as a solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

- Define a public method in the `UserControl` code behind that can be called to notify the event occurance
- Handle the `StateChanged` event in the `Window` code behind and call the defined method in the `UserControl`

Option 2:

- Implement an interface for the `StateChanged` event and implement this interface in your `Window`
- Implement a `DependencyProperty` with interface as type in the `UserControl`
- Bind the property to your `Window` when you instantiate the `UserControl`
- Register to the `StateChanged` event on property changed in the code behind of `UserControl`

Some code for demonstration how to implement and use option 2:

```
public interface IStateChanged
{
    event EventHandler StateChanged;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, IStateChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public IStateChanged StateChangedHost
    {
        get { return (IStateChanged)GetValue(StateChangedHostProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateChangedHostProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StateChangedHost.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateChangedHostProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StateChangedHost", typeof(IStateChanged), typeof(MyUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, StateChangedHost_PropertyChanged));

    private static void StateChangedHost_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = d as MyUserControl;
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            ((IStateChanged)e.OldValue).StateChanged -= self.NotifyStateChanged;
        }
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((IStateChanged)e.NewValue).StateChanged += self.NotifyStateChanged;
        }
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // implementation logic on StateChanged event
    }
}

<Window [...]>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl StateChangedHost="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a method in the User Control to notify it

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void MainWindow_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControl.StateChanged();
    }

}

public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public StateChanged()
    {
        ...
    }

}

<Window [...]>
    <Grid>
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="myUserControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Admitted, I was to lazy to write out the code for this option of my answer :)

Comment: yes but it is the simplest solution if you want something fast and "working"

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Window.WindowStateProperty, typeof(Window));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(Application.Current.MainWindow, (s, e) =>
        {
            //your code
        });
    }
}
```

Basically it tells the user control to observe WindowsStateProperty and any time that state changes it will run

Answer (score 0):

I think, that's not the right approach.

my code would look like this:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl{

  event EventHandler ParentWindowStateChanged;

  public void RaiseParentWindowStateChanged(Window sender){
       this.ParentWindowStateChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}
```

on Window.StateChanged you can call myUserControl. RaiseParentWindowStateChanged(this).

in constructor of UserControl you can add handler for event ParentWindowStateChanged like

```
MyUserControl(){
    this. ParentWindowStateChanged += (sender, args) => {
        // do something
    };
```

Regards

Steffen